# Postfix calculator using words instead of operators

Tags: c

i need to create a postfix calculator using stack. Where user will write operators in words.
Like:

- 9.5 2.3 add =

or

- 5 3 5 sub div =

My problem, that i can't understand, what function i should use to scan input. Because it's mix of numbers, words and char (=).

Comment: I suggest using [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is essentially to write a *parser*.

First, use `fgets` to read a complete line. Then use `strtok` to get tokens separated by whitespace.

After that, check if the token is a number or not. You can do that with `sscanf`. Check the return value if the conversion to a number were successful. If the conversion were not successful, check if the string is equal to "add", "sub", "=" etc. If it's not a number or one of the approved operations, generate an error. You don't have to treat strings of length 1 (aka char) different.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem, that i can't understand, what funktion i should use to scan input. Because it's mix of numbers, words and char (=).

But all of these are separated by whitespace. You could tokenize based on that and then build up a parse tree manually with `strcmp` and `strtol` or by simply having a comparision on the first character of the token (assuming that keywords cannot start with a number and there are no variables).

See [`strtok(_r)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html). The "Example" section explains how to use it in depth, but as an extract without error handling and corner cases:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char eq[] = "5 3 5 sub div =";
    for (char *tok = strtok(eq, " "); tok != NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        if (isdigit(tok[0]))
            printf("token-num: %s\n", tok);
        else if (tok[0] == '=')
            printf("token-eq: =\n");
        else
            printf("token-op: %s\n", tok);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that!